# views Filter field equal to the value of another field

Tags: views

Is there a way or a module to filter a vie by a field against the value of another field. For example uI'd is equal to the  value of another field that's given.

Comment: try and elaborate. I think you need to look in to arguments though.

Comment: Sounds as if the answer might include [Entity Views Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva), but @SDMulroy is right, this question is too vague to answer right now.

Comment: Well I like to display a usersmall profile gathered by views depending on witch user is registered for an event with the registrations module. There is a field that contains the uI'd of the registered user on one hand and the uid in the view I'be created. I have search the whole Web but I did not find a method to proof if these two fields are matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of your request you are adding a view on a node display page and want to use a field on that page as an argument in the view, if this is the case you want to add a contextual filter and under default value select php and then do a node_load or db_select to load the field from the node being viewed.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for - https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters - this allows you to use a view as a filter in another view